# VBA Excel Not Responding when opened through QTP

Tags: vba, excel, qtp, hp-uft

Action performed using QTP script --> After opening the Spreadsheet `abc.xlsm` ,when the **`Search`** macro is invoked, the search window opens and by providing search criteria in it when I hit "Enter" button, the Excel goes into Not Responding state (macro is not run completely) until the server itself gives the following:

> 408 timed out request

When the same above action is performed by manually invoking the spreadsheet. it works perfectly fine.
below is the code i am using to open the spreadsheet and performing **`Search`** macro run..

```
Dim wShell
Set oexcel= CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oexcel.Application.Visible=True
Set obook=oexcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\abc.xlsm")
Set osheet=obook.Worksheets("Search")

oexcel.Application.Run("search") 'This is the Search macro that we are runnig
wait 2

Window("search").Activate
Set wShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

wShell.SendKeys ("%")  ' this is the input search criteria 
wShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
wait 2
wShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
wait 5
```

After the above line of code is executed,the excel goes into not responding state.
However the same code works perfectly fine for another spreadsheet say `xyz.xlsm` for the same search macro. And it always works well manually.

Comment: There must be something wrong in that file or macro of that file if same thing is working for another file. Kindly double check.

Comment: @ManishChristian: well the code of the excel file is not visible to my team and issue is that same excel file works fine when action is performed manually opening it...the issue only arises when qtp opens that file

Comment: on which line exactly is the error displayed i.e on Createobject or open etc.. Try putting a breakpoint and go line by line and check and let us know

Comment: @user5612655 Error is not displayed on any code line above...it is just that after above code execution excel goes into Not Responding state and never recovers due to which further code is not executed

Answer (score 0):

XLSX/XLSM is not supported by UFT. Yea I ran into this as well. Real pain in the neck, but that's just the way it is. Just use old-style .XLS files and it will work just fine.

Comment: First thing, i was using QTP 11 and secondly UFT does support both XLSX/XLSM.